# Equation number in aligned environment after last line

Tags: equations, numbering, align

I'm using `aligned` inside `align` as follows

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
x =&22+2 \nonumber\\
  =& \begin{aligned}[t]
    &5+3\\
    &-3+4\\
    &+15-0
  \end{aligned}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

I want to have just one equation number after the very last line. 
However, I'm getting the number at the beginning of the first split line (after the second = ), 
[image]

and I cannot figure out how to move this equation number to the bottom. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Note that you need to use `&=`, not `=&`.

Comment: \begin{aligned}[t]--->\begin{aligned}[b]

Comment: Actually, the way the OP is trying to use `aligned` can only put the equation number on the same line as the equals sign. At least one of them will be misplaced. See below for a solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may want to use `split`, along with the `tbtags` option to `amsmath`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tbtags]{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
x ={} & 22+2 \\
  ={} &5+3\\
      &-3+4\\
      &+15-0
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want two numbers, then use `split` inside `align`: the alignment point will be inherited in the inner environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tbtags]{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
x ={} & 22+2 \\
\begin{split}
  ={} & 5+3\\
      &-3+4\\
      &+15-0
\end{split}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks as though it would be handy in simple use-cases in documents where you want to have good numbering either on the left or on the right (e.g. in conjunction with `leqno`).

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap Yes: `tbtags` places equation tags/numbers at the bottom of a `split` if they are at the right, or at the top if they are at the left (`leqno`).

Comment: Would you recommend any techniques for answering the OP's follow up question (in a comment on my answer: "*what would be the best way then to have a number on the first line as well*")?

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap Yes, I would. `;-)`

Comment: [*slaps head*] Well, that should have been obvious! @LuisFelipe: I recommend you accept this answer instead.

Comment: Looks like a very nice approach to solve the problem. Thanks egreg and Niel de Beaudrap for your help!

Answer (score 3):

I would change the way that you're using `aligned`: specifically, if there's no equation number on the first line, you should lump in the first line with the rest of the material in the `aligned` environment, with the `[b]` option to get the alignment of the equation number with the bottom line, as follows.

(Note the usage of `={}&` which ensures proper spacing around the `=` symbol, while aligning everything on the RHS fully to the right of the `=` sign. The `aligned` environment assumes that the `=` sign usually comes after the `&`, and does some maniuplation of space to do so: having an empty group to enforce `\mathrel` spacing around the `=`, before the `&`, has a similar effect.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}[b]
    x
={}&
    22 + 2
\\={}&
    5+3
\\&
   -3+4
\\&
   +15-0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: Edited equation putting all content into the <code>aligned</code> environment]

Comment: Now, what would be the best way then to have a number on the first line as well?

Comment: @LuisFelipe: I don't have as clever a trick for that. My solution would be `\begin{align} x ={}& 22 + 2 \\={}& 5+3 \notag\\& -3+4 \notag\\& +15-0 \end{align}` (note the use of `\notag` before each line break which is not meant to generate an equation number).

Comment: Yes, that would be the most straightforward solution for that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do the same is the following

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
%------------------------------
%-- Use of \hspace with same set length
%------------------------------
x &= 22+2 \nonumber\\
&= 5 + 3 \nonumber\\
& \hspace{5mm} -3 + 4 \nonumber\\
& \hspace{5mm} + 15 - 0 \\
%------------------------------
%-- Use of phantom
%------------------------------
&= 5 + 3 \nonumber\\
& \phantom{{} = {}} -3 + 4 \nonumber\\ 
& \phantom{{} - {}} + 15 - 0 \\
%------------------------------
%-- Use of \hspace for various lengths
%------------------------------
&= 5 + 3 \nonumber\\
& \hspace{15mm} - 3 + 4 \nonumber\\
& \hspace{30mm} + 15 - 0

\end{document}
```

[image: Three variations]

Comment: Wouldn't `\phantom{{}={}}` be better to get the exact spacing?

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap Using phantom spacing still lines the values on the right side of the = mark. As the OP's work looks and shift is needed from the first position. By using \hspace any amount of space can be placed to shift the start of the line.

Comment: To clarify what I meant, I mean e.g. `&\phantom{{}={}} -3 + 4 \nonumber\\ `. This will still shift the material on the RHS to the right of the equality symbol, and furthermore will do it by exactly the right amount, by construction.

Comment: As demonstrated in the updated code and output: \phantom is similar to use of \hspace{5mm}, but an advantage of \hspace is variation