# equation label within commutative diagram

Tags: commutative-diagrams

I would like a commutative diagram like

```
\begin{equation*} 
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=huge]     

    A \, \arrow[r] \arrow[d] & B  \arrow[d] \\ 

    C & D \arrow[l] \\

\end{tikzcd} 
\end{equation*}
```

In the commutative diagram I would like the symbol "A" to be replaced by an equation like

```
\begin{equation} \label{myequation} 
\begin{array}{rcl} 

E & = & m c^2 \\

E & = & m c^3 

\end{array} 
\end{equation}
```

and I would like to reference that equation outside, with `\ref{myequation}`.  How do I do that?

Comment: What do you precisely mean by “an equation with a label”?

Comment: Do you means something of the sort `\begin{equation*}
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=huge]
equation \, 1 with \, a \, label \, \arrow[r] \arrow[d] &  
E=m\,c^2\quad(\stepcounter{equation}\theequation) \arrow[d] \\
A                            & B  \arrow[l] \\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}`?

Comment: By "an equation with a label", do you mean a full equation, or do you mean a cross-reference to an equation labelled somewhere else in the document? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico: see my edited question above. Thanks.

Comment: @egreg: see the edited question above. thanks

Comment: @marmot see the edited question above. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Still not sure I understand your question, but here is what I think you might want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} 
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=huge,ampersand replacement=\&]     
    \label{eq:Schmarrn}(\theequation)~\left\{\begin{array}{@{}r@{\,}c@{\,}l} 
E & = & m c^2 \\
E & = & m c^3 
\end{array}\right.  \, \arrow[r] \arrow[d] \& B  \arrow[d] \\ 
    C \& D \arrow[l] \\
\end{tikzcd} \notag\stepcounter{equation}
\end{equation}
Einstein said that 
\begin{equation}\label{eq:Einstein}
E  =  m c^2
\end{equation}
and the second equality in \eqref{eq:Schmarrn} is not quite right. On the other
hand, \eqref{eq:Einstein} is correct.
\end{document}
```

[image]

As for your request. Building on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/299408/121799) you could do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}\label{eq:Schmarrn}
\makebox[\displaywidth]{
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=huge,ampersand replacement=\&]     
A  \, \arrow[r] \arrow[d] \& 
    \left.\begin{array}{@{}r@{\,}l} 
E & =  m c^2 \\
E & =  m c^3 
\end{array}\right\}  \arrow[d] \\ 
    C \& D \arrow[l] \\
\end{tikzcd}} \raisetag{24.4ex}
\end{align}
Einstein said that 
\begin{equation}\label{eq:Einstein}
E  =  m c^2
\end{equation}
and the second equality in \eqref{eq:Schmarrn} is not quite right. On the other
hand, \eqref{eq:Einstein} is correct.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, thank you. But I also want a multiline equation in place of the  "B." Further, I would like the equations to have only 2 columns, adjusted right and left, resp.  I know these should be simple changes, but I did the obvious changes, and I keep getting errors from latex.

Comment: @district9 I added something. If you want modifications, please ask a new question.

Comment: Sorry, now I accepted it. I am new to the site. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I think you want something like this:

[image]

which comes from enclosing your intended text "equation 1 with a label" in `\text{...}`.  Otherwise LaTeX considers *equation1withalabel* to be a single variable-- where it needs `\,` as a word-separator.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation*}
    \begin{tikzcd}[row sep=huge]
    \text{equation 1 with a label } \arrow[r] \arrow[d] &   
    \text{equation 2 with a label } \arrow[d] \\
                                A                       & 
                                B   \arrow[l] \\
    \end{tikzcd}
    \end{equation*}
\end{document}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, but not quite. Please see edited question above.