# Align QED symbol with last row of table

Tags: floats, theorems

MWE :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
    a & b \\
    c & d \\
\end{tabular}
\end{equation*}
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Brute force: `\vspace*{-18pt}` immediately following the `tabular`, while using the `[b]` alignment option of `tabular`..

Comment: You might also look at \taghere from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299380/amsmath-aligned-environment-correct-positioning-of-equation-number-on-the-last/299988?s=2|24.3087#299988

Comment: @JohnKormylo see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe with `\qedhere` (and `[b]` as `tabular` alignment) you could achieve what you like.

From the package documentation:

> Placement of the QED symbol can be problematic if the last part of a
>   proof environment is a displayed equation or list environment or
>   something of that nature. In that case put a `\qedhere` command at the
>   place where the QED symbol should appear, ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{tabular}[b]{cc}
    a & b \\
    c & d \\
\end{tabular}\qedhere
\end{equation*}
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

[image]