# Scale each line of a multi-line equation separately if it exceeds the linewidth

Tags: align, resize

I have many long equations, some in the order of 7-8 lines. I know that there are probably thousands of people here that instantly are urged to comment "don't scale in Latex", but I want to, so please take this as a requirement and don't suggest other methods.

I would love an environment that works in exactly the same way as align, but automatically scales lines which are too wide for a page to the appropriate width.

With appropriate width I mean that all lines except for the last are allowed the full page width, however the last one should have enough margin, such that the equation number still fits within the same line.

As an example of a very challenging equation, please take this one (I know that the below typesetting is not nice, especially the \ \ ... additional alignments, since I did not want to use && alignment tags and the appearance was fine to me):

```
\begin{align}
\epsilon_\rho &\cong \resizebox{0.92\hsize}{!}{$\Bigg[\frac{g_0 \hat{M}}{k \hat{T}_{ex}^2} \Bigg( \zeta + \frac{\hat{T}_0}{\hat{T}_0'} \ln\bigg(\frac{\hat{T}_0}{\hat{T}(\zeta)}\bigg)\Bigg) - \frac{1 + \hat{\alpha} + \hat{\gamma}}{\hat{T}(\zeta)} \left(1 - \frac{\hat{T}_{ex} - \hat{T}(\zeta)}{\hat{T}_{ex} - \hat{T}_0} (1 + \hat{\sigma}\zeta)\right)$}\nonumber\\
&\ \ \ \ + \frac{g_0}{k \hat{T}_{ex}^2} \Bigg(\zeta + \frac{\hat{T}_0}{\hat{T}_0'} \ln\bigg(\frac{\hat{T}_0}{\hat{T}(\zeta)}\bigg)\Bigg) \left(\frac{\sum\displaylimits_{i=1}^{n_\text{species}} M_i^2 \hat{n}_i}{\sum\displaylimits_{i=1}^{n_\text{species}} M_i \hat{n}_i} - \hat{M}\right)\nonumber\\
&\ \ \ \ \resizebox{0.92\hsize}{!}{$+ \frac{1 - \frac{\hat{T}_{ex} - \hat{T}(\zeta)}{\hat{T}_{ex} - \hat{T}_0} (1 + \hat{\sigma}\zeta)}{\hat{T}(\zeta)} \left(\hat{\alpha } + \hat{\gamma} - \frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n_\text{species}} M_i \hat{n}_i \alpha_i}{\hat{n}\hat{M}} - \frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n_\text{species}} M_i \hat{n}_i \gamma_i}{\hat{n}\hat{M}}\right)\vast] \delta T_{ex}$}\nonumber\\
&+ \resizebox{0.92\hsize}{!}{$\Bigg[\frac{g_0 \hat{M}}{k \hat{T}_{ex}\hat{T}_0'} \ln\left(\frac{\hat{T}(\zeta)}{\hat{T}_0}\right) - \frac{1 + \hat{\alpha} + \hat{\gamma}}{\hat{T}(\zeta)} \left(\frac{\hat{T}_{ex} - \hat{T}(\zeta)}{\hat{T}_{ex} - \hat{T}_0} (1 + \hat{\sigma}\zeta) - \frac{\hat{T}(\zeta)}{\hat{T}_0}\right)$}\nonumber\\
&\ \ \ \ + \frac{g_0}{k \hat{T}_0' \hat{T}_{ex}} \ln\left(\frac{\hat{T}(\zeta)}{\hat{T}_0}\right) \left(\frac{\sum\displaylimits_{i=1}^{n_\text{species}} M_i^2 \hat{n}_i}{\sum\displaylimits_{i=1}^{n_\text{species}} M_i \hat{n}_i} - \hat{M}\right)\nonumber\\
&\ \ \ \ \resizebox{0.92\hsize}{!}{$- \frac{\frac{\hat{T}(\zeta)}{\hat{T}_0} - \frac{\hat{T}_{ex} - \hat{T}(\zeta)}{\hat{T}_{ex} - \hat{T}_0}(1+\hat{\sigma}\zeta)}{\hat{T}(\zeta)}\left(\hat{\alpha} + \hat{\gamma} - \frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n_\text{species}} M_i \hat{n}_i \alpha_i}{\hat{n}\hat{M}} - \frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n_\text{species}} M_i \hat{n}_i \gamma_i}{\hat{n}\hat{M}}\right)\vast] \delta T_0$}\nonumber\\
&+\frac{\sum\displaylimits_{i=1}^{n_{\text{species}}} M_i \hat{n}_i \exp(\delta G_i)}{\hat{n}\hat{M}} - 1\nonumber\\ 
&+ \epsilon_n \epsilon_M
\label{eq:epsRhoCombined}
\end{align}
```

The output of above code is:

[image]

--> Any help on defining a resizedalign-environment which automatically takes care of the overlong tines (that may be identified via the resizeboxes) is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please tell us which document class and which math fonts are loaded.

Comment: Classicthesis with eulervm -> scrreprt

Comment: Which other packages do you load? How or where is `\vast` defined?

Comment: Vast is: ```\newcommand{\vast}{\bBigg@{4}}```. Don't know why other packages are important. I load many and there is no limit to load additional ones.

Comment: By stating which packages you load, you save would-be advice providers from tedious trial-and-error searching for how to possibly get your code to compile. Incidentally, `\newcommand{\vast}{\bBigg@{4}}` throws an error message.

Comment: It should compile fine without any of the additional packages I load. Classicthesis uses the regular amsmath. The compilability of the equation should not be coupled to classicthesis imo

Comment: This is something similar, however it scales the entire equation not not line by line. Also the number is below and not besides the last line: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106587/scale-an-equation-to-fit-exact-page-width/55750239#55750239

Comment: vast uses mathtools. Sorry about that.

Comment: For any multiline display defined by `amsmath` in which even one line is so wide that there is not room for the equation number on that line, the equation number will be moved down to a new line (or up, if tghe equation numbers are on the left).  The `\raisetag` facility is provided to adjust the position of a number where space is available.  See the `amsmath` user guide (`texdoc amsldoc`) for details.

Comment: Hi Barbara. I am currently using a combination of the linegoal packet to compute he remaining width and the awesome tikz-based taghere-flag. See these two links for the general ideas: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/548439/linegoal-and-align-unwanted-whitespace and   https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299380/amsmath-aligned-environment-correct-positioning-of-equation-number-on-the-last This way I can automatically scale until the end of the line and place the tag in the last with manual vertical adjustment.