# How to make the Begriffsschrift equation number be aligned at the bottom line?

Tags: equation-number, bottom

First an MWE and its output are as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tbtags]{amsmath}
\usepackage[bguq]{frege}

\begin{document}
The alignment is as desired: 
$\Fconditional[{\Facontent[1]}]{\Fconditional[{\Fcontent[1]}]{\Fconditional[{\Fcontent[1]}]{\Fcontent[1] a}{\Fcontent[1] c}}{\Fconditional[{\Fcontent[1]}]{\Fcontent[1] b}{\Fcontent[1] c}}}{\Fconditional[{\Fcontent[1]}]{\Fconditional[{\Fcontent[1]}]{\Fcontent[1] a}{\Fcontent[1] b}}{\Fcontent[2] c}}$, 
while the following one is not. Is there any solution to make the following equation number be aligned at the bottom line?

\begin{equation}
\Fconditional[{\Facontent[1]}]{\Fconditional[{\Fcontent[1]}]{\Fconditional[{\Fcontent[1]}]{\Fcontent[1] a}{\Fcontent[1] c}}{\Fconditional[{\Fcontent[1]}]{\Fcontent[1] b}{\Fcontent[1] c}}}{\Fconditional[{\Fcontent[1]}]{\Fconditional[{\Fcontent[1]}]{\Fcontent[1] a}{\Fcontent[1] b}}{\Fcontent[2] c}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, in the example the numbers isn't be aligned at the bottom line even though the `tbtags` option is invoked in the `amsmath` package. So is there any solution to fix it?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299380/amsmath-aligned-environment-correct-positioning-of-equation-number-on-the-last

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the developer of the package intended that such constructs should have their reference point at the top line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tbtags]{amsmath}
\usepackage[bguq]{frege}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\raisebox{\dimexpr\depth-\dp\strutbox}{%
  \Fconditional[{\Facontent[1]}]{\Fconditional[{\Fcontent[1]}]{\Fconditional[{\Fcontent[1]}]{\Fcontent[1] a}{\Fcontent[1] c}}{\Fconditional[{\Fcontent[1]}]{\Fcontent[1] b}{\Fcontent[1] c}}}{\Fconditional[{\Fcontent[1]}]{\Fconditional[{\Fcontent[1]}]{\Fcontent[1] a}{\Fcontent[1] b}}{\Fcontent[2] c}}%
}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, you are right. But he doesn't consider enough variety of the formulas in Frege's "Begriffsschrift, 1879" which the package serves although. And [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/650275/140814) is another problem the package couldn't or didn't solve.